# SQLite Query using wildcard % and sqlite3_mprintf %q in C

Tags: c, sqlite

Please can anyone help me figure this out, i have SQL query in C program i want to use LIKE '%STR%' in the query but STR is a variable therefore, i want to use `sqlite3_mprintf()` to parse it;

```
const char *STR = "eng";
q = "SELECT * FROM country where Name LIKE '%%q%';";
q = sqlite3_mprintf(q, STR);
```

How can i match the %q in between % %?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sqlite3_mprintf` really behaves like `snprintf` as documented, something like:

```
q = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT * FROM country where Name LIKE '%%%q%%';", STR);
```

should work.